# Import Error when Install Orange in windows 7

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation, orange

It is supposed to be straightforward but I cannot get it to work.

```
Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:55:15) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import Orange

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import Orange
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import orange
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Comment: Did you install the 64-bit version of Orange?